# How can I stop ASP.NET Core MVC from opening the home page rather than the page I'm debugging whenever I run my project?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm new to ASP.NET Core MVC (I used ASP.NET MVC before), and I can't seem to figure out how to debug pages that I am actively working on. It used to be whenever I would work on an MVC application, I could click run from the View I was in and it would open up a browser in that same page (provided I had the Controller and Action set up for it). Of course, this also depended on it being in the right folder structure as well.

Now in ASP.NET Core MVC, whenever I try to start a project from a different page, it just opens the project up from the home page. I can still navigate to the page if I modify the link in the URL, but it's very frustrating to have to do this every single time. I thought this would be a quick google search, but I'm finding that I'm having a lot of trouble getting any solution here.

What do I need to change so I can debug from the page (specifically: view) that I'm working within, rather than having to keep navigating over from the home page every time?

Comment: Which version of Visual Studio are you using?

Comment: Thank you for the response! I'm having this issue in VS 2017, VS 2019, and VS 2022. Right now, I'm actively trying to get it working in VS 2022, though I was using VS 2019 when I posted this.

Comment: You may have set the start page in the project's Debug settings.

Answer (score 0):

Open the project's Debug settings and make sure you haven't specified a start up URL.

### VS2019

*Project* -> *Project Properties*

Then change the *Launch Browser* field

[image: VS2019 Config]

### VS2022

*Project* -> *Project Properties*

*Debug* -> *General* -> *Open debug launch profiles UI*

[image: VS2022 Config 1]

Then edit the *URL* field.

[image: VS2022 Config 2]

In the images above, I have set the launch page as the Home/Index page. In your case, you will want to ensure the field is blank.

Comment: Thank you again for your assistance! Unfortunately, for both VS 2019 and VS 2022, URL section was blank and as a result, this solution did not work. However, I did find something interesting when I looked at these settings for the older MVC application: you can specify the "Current Page" as a Start Action in the project settings for Web. It seems that this is missing for some reason from MVC Core. I'm wonder if this is a feature that was removed...no idea why they would remove something so beneficial to developers, though.

Comment: I am able to get both modes to work on my machine by changing the fields above.

Comment: I don't know what to say to that; I followed exactly what you said. Both fields were blank, and still are. I can still debug my application; I just can't debug from the Current Page like I could in MVC. If you want, I can post some screenshots of my settings to prove that I did them the same as you. I really appreciate you taking the time to write out such a detailed answer, along with images and specific instructions for each version of Visual Studio. I feel frustrated that it's not working. Could there be another setting I'm not considering?

Comment: Just to be clear: I'm not saying I can't open the debugger in Chrome or something from a page other than home. I certainly can! It's just that no matter what page I open the debugger from, it always loads the home page (not the page I started the debugger from).